# How to force to open app by Universal Link in Swift likes iOS Notes app

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, universal-link

I run into an issue with Universal Link that once the Universal Link is opened by Safari, it won't able to open by its app.

Seem iOS does remember the last app used to open the link.

But when I copy the link into iOS Notes app, long-press, select **Open in "App Name"** and the issue is gone! (Check the screenshot)

1. Does anybody know how to force to open an app like iOS Notes app?
2. Or does anybody know how to check whether the URL has been remembered to open by Safari by iOS?

I did try by [open(_:options:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) & specific options `[.universalLinksOnly: true]` but it doesn't work

Thanks all

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content) article may help.

> When a user browses your website in Safari and taps a universal link in the same domain, the system opens that link in Safari, respecting the user’s most likely intent to continue within the browser. If the user taps a universal link in a different domain, the system opens the link in your app.